# Why Does My Phone Keep Linking Facebook Contacts?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, facebook

I have an HTC Desire HD with Android OS 2.2.1 installed.
The phone keeps telling me I have to link contacts that I've linked before, the problem looks to be with Facebook for HTC.
For the first couple of times it happened I actually linked all of them and now my calendar is full of repeated birthday events from Facebook.

Does anyone know what the problem might be and how to fix it?

Not sure if it matters but before this phone I had an HTC Wildfire and also linked some contacts, but they were good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in Settings->Accounts most likely you will have an account there for facebook. There may be settings for that account that allow you to choose what gets synced. Otherwise if you don't need any of it, delete the account. It won't running in the background updating facebook statuses for those contacts... Should help with battery life, memory, etc.

Hope this helps.